Counting number of occurences and restarting count after it changes
Im running a data Matrix for some Robot positioning and i am trying to get this code to generate in excel before i transition into a controller
As of now I have all of my offset variables but i fill in my matrix manually by counting the number of reoccurring offsets and and starting the count again after it changes numeric values
it looks something like this do to the nature of my robotic program and the way the counter is set up I add 1 to the first position which makes the first set of numbers greater than the rest by one
I have tried occurence counts but the issue i run into is it counts them all as a total so if i have a single 203.2 transition directlyin the middle of 16 254 occurences it still counts the 254 as 16 instead it should come out as 8 @254 1 @203.2 and 8 @ 254

Is it possible to give us a data sample using TableMarkdown Generator ? I think =SCAN() will be able to help, but I can't really tell if I'm not seeing any data. Also add in an expected output column/row.

This example might help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
